# How to change color of Text in Error messages in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, text, colors, android-darkmode

[This is the problem that I've been facing cannot change the error message in Dark Mode.]

How to edit the color of text inside the error pop-up. I've kept an error pop-up when the subject and feedback is empty and User tries to send the mail.

```
public class FeedBack extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText subject, body;
    Button send;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_feed_back);


        send = findViewById(R.id.sendFeedBT);
        subject = findViewById(R.id.subjectET);
        body = findViewById(R.id.bodyTextET);


        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                String subjectSTR = subject.getText().toString().trim();
                String bodySTR = body.getText().toString().trim();

                if(subjectSTR.isEmpty()){

                    subject.setError("Enter a Subject Please");
                    subject.requestFocus();
                }
                else if (bodySTR.isEmpty()){
                    body.setError("Enter the Message Please");
                    body.requestFocus();
                }

                else {

                    Intent email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"example@gmail.com"});
                    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subjectSTR);
                    email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, bodySTR);
                    email.setType("message/rfc822");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(email, "Choose an Email client :"));
                    finish();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a custom style like:

```
<style name="error_text_style" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/error_color</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">Italic</item>
</style>
```

Then set this style. `app:errorTextAppearance="@style/error_text_style"`

Answer (score 0):

Define error color
res/values/colors.xml

...
    ...
    #000000
    #002db3
    ...
    ...